# Как подгружать данные в таблицу без лагов

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, ios8

Дойдя до последней ячейки в таблице, с помощью метода делегата  `tableView(tableView:, willDisplayCell:, UITableViewCell:, forRowAtIndexPath:)`, я посылаю сообщение презентеру, который начинает грузить данные с сервера, в калбеке метода презентора обновляю данные через `tableView.reloadData()`, в момент срабатывания обновления таблицы - анимация скрола лагает. Как следует организовать обновление данных, чтобы не было этого лага?

Comment: Для начала, как Вы заполняете ячейки?

Comment: @VAndrJ Есть несколько контейнеров, которые содержат данные, которыми заполняются ячейки, в методе `viewDidLoad`, контроллер сообщает презентеру о том, что она загрузилась и презентер начинает возвращать данные и заполнять пустые объекты Есть несколько типов ячеек, каждая из которой имеет метод - делегат, который реализовал контроллер, и в методе `cellForRow` данные ячеек наполняются из контейнеров, в итоге все манипуляции с данными связанны с тем, что контроллер  сообщает презентеру о каких то действиях пользователя и последний наполняет контейнера, а потом дергает метод `reloadData`у таблицы

Comment: а что такое последняя ячейка? это значит, все работают, а одна тупит, или последняя ячейка в смысле есть 10 заполненных ячеек, и когда дошло до десятой, грузятся вместе следующие 10?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko моя последняя ячейка это progressCell, в которую я положил  activity indicator, место для ячейки со индикатором выделяется, если я уверен, что на сервере есть еще данные для таблицы, то есть я наполняю dataSource контейнеры, и в методе numberOfRows смотрю - смогу ли я еще что - то грузить ? dataForTable.count + 1 : dataForTable.count

Comment: тогда просто загрузку делайте на background thread

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko загрузка данных происходит асинхронно, в тот момент когда идет загрузка - проблем никаких нет, проблема лишь в момент обновления данных в таблице

Comment: интересно. а вы когда получили данные, сразу создаете все ячейки, или только видимые?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko если я правильно понимаю, ячейки создаются в cellForRowAtIndexPath, метод срабатывает только на видимых ячейках, и заполняю и только видимые, теми данными которые находятся в контейнере, а контейнер содержит все значения, которыми должны быть заполнены ячейки. В контейнере, в основном, примитивы

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавлять ячейки так:

`[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];`

Также проверь что тормозит именно обновление, а не заполнение ячеек данными. Для этого попробуй выводить пустые ячейки. Если поможет - оптимизируй `cellForRow`

Comment: Можете пожалуйста конкретней пояснить логику, как следует использовать Ваш метод добавления ячеек?

Comment: а ссылки из гугла не подойдут?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482323/uitableview-insertrowsatindexpathswithrowanimation-without-freeze-ui
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987585/ios-inserting-multiple-rows-in-uitableview-with-insertrowsatindexpaths

С оптимизацией, думаю, все понятно?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dotprox/74b0bf4af7a5b7255a8114dbca1ec5f5 я не до конца понимаю как работать с этими методами, поэтому пока разбираюсь, набрав этот код, получаю ошибку - количество строк до обновления должно быть равно количеству после обновления

Comment: а у тебя в numberOfRowsInSection уже новое количество возвращается? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060777/how-use-insertrowsatindexpaths-ios-without-reloaddata

Comment: после того, как выполняются внутренности beginLoading, презентер передает в контроллер новые данные, обновляя массив questions, который я передаю в dataSource

Comment: Выполни table.beginUpdates после того как поменяешь массив с данными. Как во всех примерах. Сейчаму тебя наоборот

Comment: сделал все, как было рекомендовано, теперь выбивает bad access

Comment: Эта ошибка уже другое значит. Смотри где ты потерял обьект, а указатель сохранил

Comment: а в каком методе стоит проделывать операции с вставками, или разницы никакой? Просто я проделываю это в методе willDisplayCell, то есть в тот момент, когда я вижу у себя ячейку с activity indicator, тогда и начинаю грузить с сервера данные

Comment: Да без разницы, вроде. Как по логике разбиваешь - данные и UI, так и делай

Comment: я буквально пару секунд назад разобрался с тем, как делать обновление таблицы с помощью вставок, но лаг обновления все равно присутствует

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42059/discussion-between--and-dot-prox).